# not full information returned in Graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql

I am trying to get the url for specific post on friends page that I liked. 
Post should be made by 3d user no friends page by these steps:

1. Put to message some url to facebook open page (e.g.
   https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ )
2. Wait while url data is loaded to message
3. Remove only url from post, all loaded data should be presented!
4. Write some text, e.g. "message"

I liked that message on friend's wall. 
  I've got it's id using fql.query request

```
select id, type from object_url where id in (select object_id from like where user_id = <your_id>)
```

But when I select data by this id using graph api or fql.query, i can't get the url from these post! !